# Why do I have this weird spacing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I can not get rid of this strange spacing between line 0 and 1. 
I want the same spacing between lines 0 and 1 as I have between line 1 and 2.

[image]

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:TABLE_VIEW_BACKGROUND_COLOR];

UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 250)];

UIImageView *headerBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addres_box"]];
[headerBackgroundImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(headerView.frame.origin.x + 10, headerView.frame.origin.y + 10, headerView.frame.size.width - 20, 160)];
[headerView addSubview:headerBackgroundImageView];

UILabel *headerTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(headerBackgroundImageView.frame.origin.x + 10, headerBackgroundImageView.frame.origin.y + 10, headerBackgroundImageView.frame.size.width - 20, 20)];
[headerTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[headerTextLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:headerTextLabel.font.pointSize]];
[headerTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[headerTextLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
[headerTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

NSString *headerTextString = @"0";
NSString *detailTextString = @"1\n2";

[headerTextLabel setText:headerTextString];
[headerView addSubview:headerTextLabel];
_headerTextLabel = headerTextLabel;

UILabel *headerDetailTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(headerTextLabel.frame.origin.x, headerTextLabel.frame.origin.y+20, headerTextLabel.frame.size.width, 140)];
[headerDetailTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[headerDetailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[headerDetailTextLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
[headerDetailTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

[headerDetailTextLabel setText:detailTextString];
[headerView addSubview:headerDetailTextLabel];
_headerDetailTextLabel = headerDetailTextLabel;

[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:headerView];
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:TABLE_VIEW_SEPARATOR_COLOR];
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: You made your first label huge, and put your second label underneath it.  Why did you make `headerTextLabel` so big?

Comment: According to his code it's just 20 points in height so it doesn't look too huge...

Comment: try to set the backgroundColor of your textlabels to another color than clearColor. Then you can see if there's really a spacing or your label is just big.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your `headerDetailTextLabel` is centered vertically, try adding more lines like "1\n2\n3\n4" and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints, I solved it by adding "sizeToFit" and now every things look good

```
[headerDetailTextLabel setText:detailTextString];
[headerDetailTextLabel sizeToFit]; //this line fixed the spacing problem
[headerView addSubview:headerDetailTextLabel];
```